# How to configure Buildozer spec file to create a webview for android?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I want to create a webview android app using buildozer. I have done this using kivy and pyjnius and it works but I don't want to use kivy, I want to use only a webframework(flask, tornado).Are there any good examples for this?

Comment: Set `p4a.bootstrap` to `webview` in your buildozer.spec.

Comment: did you test that inclement? It doesnt work for me. Do you have a working example that i can try?

Comment: No, I didn't test it, but it's still the correct way to do it. If it doesn't work, you'll need to debug that. The webview bootstrap of p4a isn't that well maintained so it could simply be broken, although it could also be a range of other things.

Comment: there is an open issue for p4a. https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1644

Comment: This issue is probably also out of date. The webview bootstrap may or may not currently work, but probably not for the same reason documented there.